# Integral part and decimal part

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Honestly, I don't know where to start with this question. How should I approach question of this topic generally

Comment: I would definitely begin by rationalising the denominator. It may help to recall that $1 < \sqrt{3} < 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac1{2-\sqrt3}&=\frac1{2-\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{2+\sqrt3}{2-\sqrt3}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt3}{(2)^2-(\sqrt3)^2}\\
&=2+\sqrt3
\end{align}

$1<\sqrt3<2$, so the decimal part of $2+\sqrt3$ has to be $\sqrt3-1$.

Since $a$ is the integral part and $b$ is the decimal part, we can let $a=3$ and $b=\sqrt3-1$.

Therefore, by substitution:
\begin{align}
a-b+\frac2b&=(3)-(\sqrt3-1)+\frac2{\sqrt3-1}\\
&=4-\sqrt3+\frac2{\sqrt3-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3+1}\\
&=4-\sqrt3+\frac{2(\sqrt3+1)}{2}\\
&=4-\sqrt3+\sqrt3+1\\
&=5
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Note/Edit**: @labbhattacharjee has a much better answer ("exact" method), so I strongly recommend using his answer. My is a "lazy" attempt, so to speak.

I plan to leave this as a comment, but my reputation is not enough...

For referencing, "integral part" is also understood as "integer part" (the section before the decimal point), and "decimal part" is the section behind it.

Because the original number is known, so the best way is to write it down in decimal number, or
$\frac{1}{2-\sqrt 3} = 2+\sqrt 3 = 3.73205$

Therefore $a=3$ and $b=0.732050808$

We have $a-b+\frac{2}{b}= (something) $
The rest can be done via calculator (or Wolfram Alpha, or Mathematica...)
(I have something close 5, for reference)

For a more general approach, I suggest to "calculate" the number, as in turning the fraction into a decimal number, then the rest would be simply splitting the integer and decimal part, and doing the math

Comment: $$2+\sqrt3=3+\sqrt3-1,$$ $$\dfrac2b=\dfrac2{\sqrt3-1}=\sqrt3+1$$

Comment: Note that using $a = 3$, but with $b = \sqrt{3} - 1$, then doing appropriate simplifications of $a - b + \frac{2}{b}$ (e.g., as shown in [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee)'s comment), I got *exactly* $5$. I recommend using exact values, like lab and I did, instead of decimal approximations.